# Why does iPad run out of batteries while it's plugged in?

Tags: ipad, battery

I'm playing Vain Glory with my iPad Pro plugged into the 12W adapter via the supplied Lightning cable. Screen goes black, battery dead. Takes a few minutes to come back on.

Why on earth did the device turn off even though it's plugged into the mains? Why does it show the battery dead symbol, instead of just turning on using the power from the mains to operate?

This is so frustrating and lame.

Comment: Maybe the lightning cable isn't making good contact? Sometimes you need to remove the cable and plugin again... Do you see a loading indicator in top right corner of iPad?

Comment: Are you using the 12.9 inch iPad Pro?

Comment: Yes I am... but why should it matter? When you buy a computing device, especially a "pro" one, the expectation is, when it's plugged into the wall, then IT WILL NOT FREAKING RUN OUT OF POWER. I never got any warnings on the screen that I was risking the device turning off, and I there was not any obvious warning labels on the adapter or iPad to disclose the fact that the power adapter is not, in fact, capable of powering the device when it's in use. I consider this to be a manufacturing defect and will be demanding a replacement adapter that does actually work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 12.9" iPad Pro can use power faster than the 12W power adapter can supply it. That's why it can run out of power when running for example a game, even though it is connected to the charger.

To avoid that, use the 29W Apple power adapter instead. The 29W adapter is not supplied with the iPad Pro, but must be bought seperately.

Comment: Pretty ridiculous they don't include a functional power supply with a "pro" device. That really ticks me off. Apple will be hearing from me about this!!

Comment: Well, it is your opinion that a power adapter needs to be able to charge a device even when it is in "heavy" use. There's no law that requires it - and other device makers have done the same thing in the past.

Comment: I don't know if you're right or not. I have certainly never had any device where the power plug would not allow it to run indefinitely. 99.9% of the time, that is the point of the power plug: to let a device run without needing the batteries to necessarily be charged and without being subject to threat of the battery running out on you. Also, it was not in heavy use, I was just playing a game, which is a very normal use case scenario for an iPad. I'm pretty sure that's not just my opinion; I'm pretty sure if you went on the street most people would agree that's a power adapter's purpose.

Comment: If you bought a Mac Pro and it turned off randomly while it was plugged in, and someone said, "It's just your opinion that a computer should have enough power to run while plugged into the wall," what would your response to that be?

Comment: Gaming can be "heavy usage" - i.e. many games are very taxing on a tablet. A Mac Pro hasn't got a battery at all, so ofcourse you would expect the power supply to be able to supply power at all times. I'm not saying it is unreasonable to expect a charger to be able to cover the power usage of the device while in use, however I'm just saying that historically - it is not a new thing for a charger not to be able to do so.